# Are Lokijs ID's Unique?

Tags: lokijs

Are lokijs id's ($loki) unique?

if I have 2 documents from one collection with $loki:1 and $loki:2 as id's, and I delete $loki:1, the next one I create should it be $loki:3 ???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's correct. Collections keep track of the last ID that was created and assign the a `lastId + 1` value to the `$loki` property of the next object you insert in a collection. You can check the value of the last id by checking `collection.maxId` and deduce the next id by simply adding 1 to that.

Comment: just to make sure, `$loki` values are assigned automatically?